# Want to access response from wp_remote_post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am calling api using wp_remote_post() method.I am getting below response from api

```
  Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [cache-control] => no-cache
            [pragma] => no-cache
            [content-length] => 100
            [content-type] => application/json
            [content-encoding] => deflate
            [expires] => -1
            [server] => Microsoft-IIS/8.5
            [x-aspnet-version] => 4.0.30319
            [date] => Fri, 27 May 2016 12:47:01 GMT
            [connection] => close
        )

    [body] => {"ResponseStatus":false,"ResponseData":null,"ErrorData":{"ErrorCode":"E0002","Error":"Email already registered.","ErrorDetail":"Email already registered."}}
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [filename] => 
)
```

I want to access all properties of above object

I am trying to access using below code

```
$res->ResponseStatus;
```

but it print nothing.

Comment: That's a really weird response...Are you sure that's the response you're getting?

Comment: i am getting whole response like below

Comment: what about json_decode($response['body']); ?

Comment: after decode it retruns object like "object(stdClass)#575 (3) {
  ["ResponseStatus"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["ResponseData"]=>
  NULL
  ["ErrorData"]=>
  object(stdClass)#576 (3) {
    ["ErrorCode"]=>
    string(5) "E0002"
    ["Error"]=>
    string(25) "Email already registered."
    ["ErrorDetail"]=>
    string(25) "Email already registered."
  }
}"

Comment: how can i use ResponseStatus property of above object

Comment: then do $responseBody = json_decode($response['body']); and you can then use $responseBody->ResponseStatus

Answer (score 6):

```
$request = wp_remote_post( $url, array( 'body' => $args ) );

if ( is_wp_error( $request ) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $request ) != 200 ) {
    return false;
}
$response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request ) );
```

Comment: You should use `json_decode` as the response body is a json string. Using unserialize can result in code being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading, and a malicious user may be able to exploit this.